# Visual Studio Code - Shortcut - Collapse all files in explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Can you anyone provide the shortcut for collapse all files in visual studio code explorer?

Comment: These are the keyboard shortcuts for VS Code (Windows). [VS Code Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

Comment: Is it possible to collapse only folders and parents, that don't have files opened?

Comment: related: [How to collapse sub-folders when a folder is closed in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57238859/11107541)

Answer (score 106):

I personally prefer not to create new shortcuts. As @Mark pointed out on the answer of @JayChase there is an existing shortcut, but it requires the explorer to be in focus. Therefore I combine the shortcut mentioned by @JayChase with another standard shortcut, to get the desired behaviour.

- `command + 0` (focusses on explorer).
- `command + left-arrow`

An additional benefit over this approach is that I usually want to focus on the explorer view if I want to collapse the folders.

Comment: The `0` has to be the `0` above the letters on the keyboard - not the `0` on the keypad (at least on a Windows machine).

Comment: This works like a charm on MacOS. I personally prefer using out-of-the-box shortcuts as opposed to creating a custom keybinding I will need to set on every machine I use VS Code on in the future.

Comment: This is a funny question! The answer keeps changing every few months. This one worked for me. @microsft - get you s*it together!

Comment: You could also use `command + shift + e` to focus on the file explorer.

Comment: +1 from me because I don't wanna be worrying about my new shortcut clashing with existing shortcuts that I might need in future

Comment: what is the reverse shortcut for unfold?

Answer (score 87):

Open the `Keyboard Shortcut` by pressing `Ctrl + K` then `Ctrl + S` and search for `Collapse`, you will see the `Collapse Folders in Explorer` key binding (It is empty by default). Press the **+** button to add your desired key binding.

Now you can enjoy your shortcut.

Comment: Thanks it works! I assigned `Ctrl + Alt + 0`

Answer (score 38):

it's `cmd/ctrl + shift + up-arrow`

Comment: This command un-collapses the already-collapsed folders, but OP was looking for a   way to collapse all files. @ghostbbbmt-MSP answer is for that.

Answer (score 18):

You can collapse all folders using `cmd/ctrl left-arrow`.

Comment: This does require that focus already be in the explorer.  A keybinding would not.  Depends on use.

Answer (score 13):

First, click anywhere in the explorer window to activate it, then use the shortcut.

On Windows and Linux.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>

On Mac:

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>

Comment: `ctrl` + `left arrow` works!

Answer (score 5):

The below solution:

- Works without a mouse
- Works even if a different primary sidebar (Search, Source Control, Run and Debug, etc.) was last open
- Works out of the box / does not require adding new shortcut(s)

Solution:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (*Corresponding command is View: Show Explorer.
   For macOS:* <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (*Corresponding command is list.collapseAll.
   For macOS:* <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>)

Answer (score 2):

When the Explorer is active, you could use the Workbench `list` based shortcuts. `list` based shortcuts include collapse, collapse all, expand, expand all, toggle expand/collapse

To see what are the shortcuts open [`Keyboard Shorcuts`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) -> Search for `list.` . Here you find shortcuts for collapse, collapse all, expand, expand all, toggle expand/collapse. These shortcuts work when the Explorer is active, as the Explorer works as a list.

Below is a screenshot for Mac.
[image: Collapse shortcuts for list]

If you would like to define a shortcut, without activating the Explorer, then I would recommend - `cmd+k ctrl+c`. You could add this by opening [`Keyboard Shorcuts`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) -> Search for `Collapse Folders in Explorer` -> Click the edit button after hovering over the the Command you want to edit.