# How to collapse sub-folders when a folder is closed in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I collapse a folder, I want the sub-folder to be collapsed as well. Right now when I collapse a folder and re-open it, the sub-folders stay as they were while the folder was being closed. I want the behaviour where collapsing the folder also collapses the sub-folders.

Answer (score 18):

You can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> a folder to recursively expand or collapse it. However, I don't think it's possible to make that the default, since [keybindings don't support mouse input](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3130).

Comment: [Note that](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66811) this feature only expands sub-directories that were collapsed with previous `Alt` + `Click`. There is no feature to expand all sub-directories with one click in VS Code.

Answer (score 13):

The new 1.42 (Q1 2020) VSCode might help:

> ### [Two-step collapse in multi-root Explorer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/ba6965142c56f0bc981c65a84f9f7ef2d702d6e9/release-notes/v1_42.md#two-step-collapse-in-multi-root-explorer)
>
> When you are using a multi-root workspace, the Collapse Folder button in the File Explorer now has a two-step behavior, where:
>
> - the first click will collapse all folders within each top-level, and
> - the second click will collapse the top-level folders.
>
> The Search view already has this behavior.

[image: Two-step File Explorer collapse button -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_42/2-step-collapse.gif]